# Какое количество дисков для raid-10 может выйти из строя без потери данных?

Tags: hdd, ssd, raid

Для raid-10 из 4-х дисков критичным может оказаться 2 диска. Т.е. сбой одного диска никогда не нарушит данные. Если интересует вариант raid-10 (софтовый), при котором
выход из строя двух дисков гарантированно не нарушит данные, то сколько их в raid
ставить? Просто в on-line калькуляторах (разных) получаю и при 8-ми дисках в raid-10
(на любых количествах в группе), что только один битый диск никогда не порушит данные.
Как правильно считать количество дисков в raid-10, чтобы гарантированно сохранить данные при выходе двух, или трех дисков?

Comment: Если replication factor = 2, и {replication_factor} зеркалирующих диска выйдут из строя, то весь массив рухнет. Я бы на вашем месте смотрел в строну RAID-5/6, я подробно не читал, но вроде именно они ориентированы на большое количество дисков и б*о*льшую отказоустойчивость, чем 0/1

Comment: Спасибо за участие, просто критично по скорости записи, а так-же 'софтовый', поэтому raid-10. Не пойму, разве увеличением количества дисков/групп в raid-10 нельзя увеличить 'отказоустойчивость' ...

Comment: ну смотрите. RAID-0 обеспечивает увеличение скорости, а RAID-1 оебспечивает зеркалирование, и, тем самым, отказоустойчивость. Таким образом вы можете увеличить скорость в N раз, сделав массив RAID-0 из N устройств, и увеличить возможные потери дисков до M-1, сделав каждое устройство RAID-1 массивом из M дисков. Тем не менее, для полной потери кластера достаточно потери любого RAID-0 устройства, а для утого нужно, чтобы в RAID-1 диске протухли все физические диски. Поэтому ваша отказоустойчивость на самом деле ограничена только количеством дисков в RAID-1 массиве,..

Comment: RAID-0 же отвечает исключительно за производительность. Более того, этот массив будет работать со скоростью самого медленного диска, поэтому ожидаемый прирост производительности вы можете и не получить. Поэтому я еще раз советую вам посмотреть в сторону 5/6, софт-не софт здесь не играет роли, при реализации на софте вы потеряете как на 0/1, так и на 5/6.

Comment: А как по Вашему, какое максимальное количество дисков (в raid-10 из восьми дисков) может выйти из строя без потери данных?

Comment: Вы не должно ориентироваться на максимальное, потому что это небезопасно. Вам нужно ориентироваться на минимальное, потому что только таким образом можете запланировать отказ. И еще раз, вам не нужен 10, вам нужен 5 или 6. В raid-10 из восьми дисков возможны как минимум две конфигурации, поэтому нельзя сказать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAID-10 в стандартном режиме дублирования без потери данных переживёт выпадение одного любого диска, устойчивость от выпадения второго не гарантирована. Собран как зеркало поверх страйпа, или наоборот страйп поверх зеркала, или mdadm (который ни то ни другое) - разницы не имеет, гарантирована устойчивость только без любого одного диска. Особое внимание на "любого диска".

Каждый блок данных в RAID-10 зеркалируется по двум дискам, из-за этого общая потеря ёмкости - половина. Но поэтому же, если вам не повезло, и выпали хоть даже из 10 дисков только те два, на которых были зеркала одного сектора данных - этот сектор читать больше неоткуда. В случае большой удачи выпадения именно нужных дисков - можно потерять до половины накопителей массива.

Например, в linux raid aka mdadm, возможно указать, сколько копий данных должно реплицироваться по дискам. Например, 3 копии данных на 6 дисках дадут вам возможность пережить выпадение любых двух дисков и не любых 4. Цена этого - доступная ёмкость массива. Вам будет доступна ёмкость только двух дисков из 6.

RAID5 и RAID6, о которых вам в комментариях пишут - переживут выпадение одного и двух дисков соответственно. Выход из строя любого второго диска в raid5 или любого третьего в raid6 - фатален и влечёт потерю всего массива. Цель и удел этих уровней рейда - подстраховаться от смерти диска, но при этом как-нибудь более дёшево, чем зеркало. RAID5 уменьшит форматируемую ёмкость массива на размер только одного диска, RAID6 - на ёмкость только двух дисков. А не вполовину, как RAID1 или RAID10.

Например, из 12 дисков по 1 тб можно собрать:

- RAID5 ёмкостью в 11 Тб, можно потерять любой 1 диск
- RAID6 ёмкостью в 10 ТБ, можно потерять любые 2 диска
- RAID10 ёмкостью в 6 ТБ, можно потерять любой 1 диск
- RAID10 ёмкостью в 4 ТБ, если настроить, что можно потерять любые 2 диска

Казалось бы, зачем тогда так активно используют raid10 с такой разницей по ёмкости? Ответ: из-за производительности. У RAID10 запрос на чтение может обслужить любой диск из пары, значит у нормально сделанного RAID10 - запросы на чтение можно распараллелить по разным дискам. У raid5/6 один исходный блок данных хранится только в одном месте. Чтобы его прочитать из избыточных данных - надо будет прочитать этот сегмент со всех дисков сразу и применить немного математики. Затем, RAID5/6 помедленнее на записи. И куда более драматичная разница в деградировавшем виде, т.е. если один диск у нас выпал. RAID5/6 просаживаются по производительности более чем чувствительно.

Сколько дисков можно потерять - решает задача. Напомню только, что когда выпавший диск заменяется на новый и начинается процесс синхронизации массива - это очень опасное время, на старые диски нагрузка резко возрастает и может помереть кто-нибудь ещё. Поэтому RAID5 используют довольно редко, RAID6 не намного дороже для этих задач, но подстраховывает на время пересборки масива.

И ещё важный момент, который надо при разговорах о рейдах всегда указывать: RAID это не бекап. Бекап у вас должен быть всё равно.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Я правильно понял, что для raid-10, чтобы можно было потерять (максимум) 2 диска, нужно минимум 12 дисков, причем еще и особо настроить, т.е. с потерей более половины емкости, как в Вашем примере. Не подскажете пример такой настройки? Может есть инфа толковая в инете, чтобы прикинуть время записи такой сборки.

Comment: Касательно только mdadm: чтобы пережить выпадение любых 2 дисков, вам потребуется любое число дисков начиная с 3 штук. (вырожденный случай, ведёт себя как RAID1). 4 диска, 5 дисков - не проблема, поэтому в ответе и сказал, что у mdadm raid10 - это что-то отдельное. Ёмкость массива считается элементарно: сырая ёмкость устройств делить на количество копий данных. Глянул в ман, вам нужен аргумент `--layout=`. Например, `mdamd -C /dev/md0 -l 10 --layout=n3 -n 6 /dev/sd[a-f]1` для массива из 6 дисков с 3 копиями данных.

Comment: "в linux raid aka mdadm, возможно указать, сколько копий данных должно реплицироваться по дискам" -- буду по этой теме читать, спасибо за подсказку ... только сходу не нахожу ничего толкового по теме ... Думал есть готовая таблица-раскладка / калькулятор, которая покажет зависимость под raid-10 : число безвредных отказов винтов к их количеству в рейде и ~скорость (чтение/запись) под каждый вариант.

Comment: Вот нужен софтовый рейд на debian из одинаковых дисков. Нужна условно максимальная производительность на запись и устойчивость к потере сразу двух (вначале думалось и трёх) дисков. Винтов 8 штук есть, но можно при необходимости увеличить. Но цену вопроса никак не пойму, т.е. была бы таблица зависимости ... с привязкой к скорости записи ... может на 10-12 винтах можно 'чудеса' сотворить, или, наоборот ...

Comment: Запись последовательная? Грубая калькуляция: скорость записи одного диска * количество дисков / количество записываемых копий данных. raid10 штука простая и глупая, поэтому довольно внятно масштабируется по количеству дисков. Но от того, что резервные копии данных надо писать в несколько мест никуда не деться. Чтение же - растёт пропорционально числу дисков и по линейным и по случайным запросам. Стоит ещё с размером chunk поиграться - блоки какого именно размера размазывать, для последовательной записи можно увеличить.

Comment: запись скорее рандомная, спасибо за подсказки и участие